# Anime with male protagonist who conceals his red eyes

Tags: story-identification, anime

The anime is about a male main character who has red eyes. He wears contacts most of the time to cover the eyes. It might have something to do with supernatural stuff. I know his mother tried to murder him. Also there was a detective involved with him. He forgave his mother after finding out the reason. I think his mother was raped by her kidnapper who had red eyes and that is why the main character has red eyes. There is also a girl that fits into this story well.

I know this might not be helpful but I remember some things vaguely:
(These may or may not have happened)

- Something about cars going very fast under a bridge.
- A swingset scene with the detective, main character, and/or the main character and bullies.
- Something on the rooftop in the building and kidnappings.

Comment: What's an MC? Master of Ceremonies? Main Character?

Answer (score 7):

Could this be **[Psychic Detective Yakumo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychic_Detective_Yakumo)**?

The [wiki page](http://shinreitanteiyakumo.wikia.com/wiki/Azusa_Saitou) for this character mentions rape, red eyes and a kidnapping as key plot points.

> She was kidnapped and held captive when she was young. She eventually
>   managed to escape, but was raped by the man with red eyes who is now
>   Yakumo's biological father. She tried to kill Yakumo when he was young
>   because of his red eye as she was told his red eye would cause him to
>   kill people.